# Use Set .forEach() to add items to a specified property of an object

Tags: javascript, object, foreach, set

I have a function that returns a set of column numbers and an object defined with some properties

```js
for (let row of excelSheet)
{
  let item = {
    property1: row[column]
    property2: row[column]
    property3: row[column]
  }
}
```

let's say though that values for property three can be found in more than one column and therefore the set that is returned from the column has more than one value. I tried to set `property3:` to

```
row[Number(columnSet.foreach(function(v){return v})]
```

however, nothing seems to populate in the item and the console logs undefined for that property. Is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are multiple values, you probably want an array instead. Use `.map` to iterate over the Set and access the appropriate row, so that the value of `item.property3` is an array of values of `row[column]`s:

```
property3: [...columnSet].map(column => row[column])
```

```js
const columnSet = new Set([2, 4]);
const row = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const obj = {
  property3: [...columnSet].map(column => row[column])
};

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: fantastic! Not sure why mapping didn't even occur to me I neglected that forEach returns undefined